# Dynamic Place in Blender - Live moving objects with physics Interactive rigid body

Tags: objects, physics, transforms, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

Is there an add-on or an option in Blender, to have a live objects moving with physics.
I have attached here an example with what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: There isn't any solution yet that I'm aware of, which is why I'm currently working on an addon doing such, here's a wip preview: https://twitter.com/i/status/1610402645788839936 From which software is that coming?

Comment: This example is from Cinema 4D R26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got some time to finish this, hurrah ^^!

Hope you'll like it as much as I do :)

You can find the addon here: https://fairmarket.land/product/phyx-drag

Cheers!